# Azure AD B2C Graph API following login?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure AD B2C on a customer facing website. Users can complete a sign-up policy to register an account, and this is working successfully, with the isNew claim coming back when the user first completes the policy.

We want to add the user to a specific group on first login, based on some business logic. As I envision it, we will just add a handler for the SecurityTokenValidated notification, look at the isNew claim, and then update the new user as needed.

This appears to require use of the Graph API, but I'm unclear on how to finish setting up the AD B2C tenant and configure the Graph API to work server side in this case. How should I approach this case where the site needs to interact with the Graph API while the user is logged in?

Thanks for any pointers/examples.

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried? Are you asking in general how to make calls to the Graph API? Have you tried something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)?

Comment: I attempted to walk through that article, and was unable to get anywhere with the Powershell cmdlets.  I called Get-Credentials, using my login info, which is set up as a Global administrator in the b2c tenant, but subsequent calls all failed saying it was an invalid login.

Comment: I tried that link but couldn't get the auth cmdlets to work with my credentials, despite being a global admin in the b2c tenant. I switched to old azure portal, and created app there, indicating AAD and Graph API under required permissions, and was then able to get a call working using the sample code from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/) and using the secret key. I'm still not clear on if I need to retrieve an app token once per session, or just once on webapp startup, and how to keep it active.

Comment: If you are using our client libraries, this should all be handled in the background. Otherwise, you can look into our [token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#introduction) and [refresh tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

Answer (score 1):

> How should I approach this case where the site needs to interact with the Graph API while the user is logged in?

As far as I know, the Azure AD B2C tenant only support the **client credential** flow to acquire the token for the Azure AD Graph.

At present, the **OAuth2.0 authorization code flow** for Azure AD B2C only support to acquire the token for your app's own backend web API(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code#2-get-a-token)).

So in your scenario, you are not able to get the access token when the web app startup. You can get the app-only token when you needed. And as Shawn Tabrizi mentioned, if you were using the Active Directory Authentication Library, it will manage the lifetime of token using token cache by default.

More detail about **Client Credential** flow, you can refer [this document](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) those it works for the Microsoft Graph, however it is easy to change the resource to Azure AD Graph.